# ListFragment not showing all items from CursorLoader

Tags: android, android-cursorloader

I'm trying to display all rows from my content provider in a ListFragment using a CursorLoader.  But it only shows the first 10 items, how do I get it to display all items?

```
@Override public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    setEmptyText("No newsfeed items");
    setHasOptionsMenu(false);

    newsfeedCursorAdapter = new NewsfeedCursorAdapter(getActivity(), null);
    this.setListAdapter(newsfeedCursorAdapter);
    getActivity().getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);      
}

@Override public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle b){
    return new CursorLoader(getActivity(), baseUri, projection, null, null, null);
}

@Override public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data){
    newsfeedCursorAdapter.changeCursor(data);
}

@Override public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader){
    newsfeedCursorAdapter.changeCursor(null);
}
```

when the activity get displayed, i see the:

> "no newsfeed items",

then an `intentservice` pulls in data from a webservice and populates my content provider, I can see all 30 items in the sqlite db by manually selecting all items from the table through the adb shell.

Content provider:

> query method has cursor.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
>
> insert method has  getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);

Comment: Is it the default behaviour of a cursorloader to only display 10 items?

Comment: *Is it the default behaviour of a cursorloader to only display 10 items?* - No, I would say to double check your `query` method of the `ContentProvider`.

Comment: I'm not passing any additional selection args in onCreateLoader, so I'm not sure why it's only displaying 10 items?

Comment: Do I also need to implement onCreateView in my ListFragment?

Comment: calling getCount() on my CursorAdapter only returns 10 items, while there are 30 items in the sqlite db.